# Joomla giving blank screen after http error 500

Tags: php, joomla, module

I had Joomla site giving an HTTP error `500` on both the frontend and backend.

I changed the permissions on index.php to `755` but no luck.

I noticed it was running PHP 5.6 so I upgraded to PHP 7 and now it's just giving me a blank screen. I checked the error log and I'm receiving the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/uploadprogress.so' - 
/usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/uploadprogress.so: undefined symbol: 
zend_ini_string_ex in Unknown on line 0
```

I was also getting this error beforehand. Any ideas on what module I can / should disable to fix this?

Comment: maybe start with the 'uploadprogress.so' module.

Comment: Does this mean just trying to disable to disable it at first?

Answer (score 0):

The warning that you're seeing has likely nothing to do with the blank page. Assuming you already set the `$error_reporting` to `maximum` in your configuration.php file and you didn't see the error, then try disabling system plugins one by one (disable the last ones installed first) until the problem is fixed.

Now, if you still see the error, then it is possible that you didn't install the PHP MySQL module when you updated to PHP 7. This issue is common when you have WHM, essentially, you will need to install the module through EasyApache. See [this post](https://www.itoctopus.com/0-the-mysql-adapter-mysqli-is-not-available-joomla-error-after-updating-to-php-7-2) about this.